# Naming USB Volumes In Bulk?

Tags: usb, disk-volume

I am bulk buying some promotional USB sticks from Alibaba.

I want to have a custom name for a volume on the USB stick and a custom logo.
For windows I have a hidden AUTORUN.inf and icon.ico file which both work well. The AUTORUN.inf allows a custom name of any amount of characters as well.

I have setup a hidden .Volumeicon.icns for mac which is working well. BUT.... I can't seem to get a custom name to work. It seems that only 11 characters can be used (exFAT), although that doesn't seem to work either according to the supplier.

Is there a type of file that will set the USB stick name similar to the AUTORUN.inf for windows? Something I can just send to the supplier that will automatically name the USB stick for Mac? Or is there some other method other than manually naming each USB stick volume individually? Is there any way to name the volume more than 11 characters?